# UITextField with FontAwesome

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, font-awesome

I'm trying to put a FontAwesome search icon into an UITextField. This does not work though as FontAwesome and actual placeholder of the text field are two different fonts (that's what I guess at least).
This is how it currently looks:

```
searchField.placeholder = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .search) + " Enter country or city"
searchField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
```

Is there any way I can realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both font awesome icon and your place holder string will work together if you use the FontAweSome font instead of your system font.

Sample code below:

```
searchField.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 14)
searchField.placeholder = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .search) + " Enter country or city"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to do the same thing, and I did it this way (without use placeholder):

**Swift 2**

In viewDidLoad method:

```
 textField.delegate = self

 textField.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(16)
 textField.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Search)
 textField.textColor = UIColor.grayColor();
```

In delegate method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.font = UIFont(name: "YOUR FONT", size: 16.0)
    textField.text = ""
    textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor();
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) { 
    if(textField.text == "") {
        textField.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(16)
        textField.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Search)
        textField.textColor = UIColor.grayColor();
    }
}
```